# Firing off local notification at set time

Tags: ios, swift

I've mixed and matched code from tutorials and have :

```
@IBAction func scheduleLocal(sender: AnyObject) {
    var getCurrentYear = dateFire.year
    var getCurrentMonth = dateFire.month
    var getCurrentDay = dateFire.day

    dateFire.year = getCurrentYear
    dateFire.month = getCurrentMonth
    dateFire.day = getCurrentDay
    dateFire.hour = 15
    dateFire.minute = 1
    dateFire.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()

    var calender: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
    var date: NSDate = calender.dateFromComponents(dateFire)!

    guard let settings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings() else { return     }

    if settings.types == .None {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Can't schedule", message: "Either we don't have permission to schedule notifications, or we haven't asked yet.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }

    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.fireDate = date
    notification.alertBody = "Hey you! Yeah you! Swipe to unlock!"
    notification.alertAction = "be awesome!"
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    notification.userInfo = ["CustomField1": "w00t"]
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

Before, I was using this code to send a local notification with a time interval from now, but I want to be able to set it to a specific time..

I wanted a notification to go off at 3:01, and this is my code for that. 
No notification went off.

What am I missing?

Edit: When printing out "date", it's printing: a weird date and the time is four hours ahead. My simulator has the correct time, and I've tried system and default time zones.

I also tried setting my test up where I set the year/month/day manually, and set the hour where it was 4 hours earlier so it'd give me the right time, the time printed correctly but still didn't fire off the notification when that time hit.

Comment: Print the date you generate, what is it

Comment: 0001-01-01 19:57:02 +0000 is what came up..shouldn't this just be printing 15:01:00 ?

Comment: Okay, so no matter what time I set it's pushing it forward 4 hours. My simulator displays the correct time. I've tried systemtimezone and defaulttimezone and they both do the same thing. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think the printed time is wrong, I think it's just showing it to you in GMT.